# Cómo corregir este Insert en SQLLITE y FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, sqlite

buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código hecho en flutter y SQLite

```
import 'package:crud/models/note.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

class Operation{

  static Future<Database> _openDb() async{
    return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(),'note.db'),
      onCreate: (db,version){
        return db.execute("CREATE TABLE notes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, content TEXT)");
      },
      version: 2
    );
  }

  static Future<void> insert(Note note) async{
    Database database = await _openDb();
    database.insert("notes", note.toMap());
    return ;
  }

  static Future<List<Note>> notes() async{
    
    Database database = await _openDb();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> notesMap = await database.query("notes");
    print(notesMap);
    for (var n in  notesMap){
        print("_____" + n['title']);
    }
    // notesMap[i]['id']
    return List.generate(notesMap.length, (i) => Note(id:notesMap[i]['id'], title:notesMap[i]['title'], content:notesMap[i]['content']));
  }
}

***************************
esta es mi clase 
***************************
class Note{
  final int? id;
  final String? title;
  final String? content;

  Note({int? this.id, String? this.title, String? this.content});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return {'id': id, 'title': title, 'content': content};
  }
}
```

con un boton mando a llamar mi insert pero me muestra el siguiente mensaje

> /SQLiteLog( 4422): (1) table notes has no column named content in "INSERT INTO notes (id, title, content) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)"

no entiendo que me falta me podrian ayudar.

Comment: Hola! Pues eso, tu insert busca poner en la tabla `notes` un valor `content` en la columna `content` y sqllite dice que esa tabla no tiene esa columna.

Comment: muchas gracias pero segun mi codigo si existe la creo en el onCreate creo mi tabla y el campo no existe no entiendo donde esque se pierde o por que no la encuentra o que es lo que me falta.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia la versión de la BD

```
return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(),'note.db'),
      onCreate: (db,version){
        return db.execute("CREATE TABLE notes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, content TEXT)");
      },
      version: 3
    );
```

Y vuelve a correr tu código. Es muy probable que hayas modificado la tabla y añadido el campo, pero la bd que intentas usar aún tiene la tabla vieja sin el campo.

Podrías hacer drop y recrear todas las tablas en el método onUpdate, aumentando la versión de la BD cada vez que cambies el esquema para evitar estos líos en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo en lo que dice AlfaBravo, pero para que no tengas que estar cambiando la versión cada vez que modifiques la base de datos, te recomiendo que en vez de cambiar la versión, desinstales la aplicación de tu dispositivo y la vuelvas a correr. Así evitas cambiar la versión.